# Metrics for evaluating low contrast

Tags: variance, image-processing

Hi i want to ask question. I have a dataset consists of images. Some of the images have very low contrast. I want to be able to measure the contrast in my dataset not by visual observation but by a evaluation metrics. For now i know one metric to use is variance. My question is how to properly calculate the variance of the image, suppose if i have 3 channel image (RGB), do i have to calculate the variance on each channel or take the intensity channel (maybe convert to LUV first- then compute variance on L) ? Or if there any other metrics to use is welcomed. Thankyou.

Comment: Is it customary to define contrast just in terms of variance? Suppose image A shows a room half lit by sun coming through a window, the parts in the sunbeam are hard to distinguish because all are about equally bright and the other parts are hard to distinguish because they are all almost black. Image B is mainly an herringbone pattern with crisp black and white areas near to each other. The two images might have equal variances, but one seems poor 'contrast' and the other high. Does frequent crisp change btw light and dark count for anything?

Comment: Also I can imagine hi 'contrast' bwt blu/brn or green/magenta that would disappear in a b/w rendering of images. Is contrast defined in terms of brightness alone or do color differences matter? // If there is no established defn of contrast, explaining/showing what you mean by contrast might get you more helpful answers. If there is an established defn, even if not statistical, I wonder if rate of change btw _nearby_ regions needs to be captured by some statistical measure. // In 1-D, is `0000011111` just as "contrasty" as `0011100011`? // Have you tried image compressibility as criterion.